# Row selection by input values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting input from user and trying to select the specific row in a data frame. But I cant.

My code:

```
batteryserialnumber_in = input("Enter Batter_id [INSMOMAHXXXXXXXXXXXX]: ")
Time_in  = input("Enter Time [Hr:Min:Sec]: ")
Date_in  = input("Enter the date YYY-MM-DD format:")

res2 = df1.isin(df1['Date']=='Date_in' & df1['batteryserialnumber']== batteryserialnumber_in') &  df1['Time']=='Time_in'
```

My data frame has the date [YYYY-MM-DD] and battery serial, but no time [hr:mm:sec] column.

Comment: What error are you getting? And what does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only the rows in the dataframe that satisfies your filter condition based on the user input the following should do the trick:

```
batteryserialnumber_in = input("Enter Batter_id [INSMOMAHXXXXXXXXXXXX]: ")
Time_in = input("Enter Time [Hr:Min:Sec]: ") 
Date_in = input("Enter the date YYY-MM-DD format:")

res2 = df1.loc[(df1['Date']==Date_in) & (df1['batteryserialnumber']==batteryserialnumber_in) & (df1['Time']==Time_in)]
```

Comment: These not accepting my input

Comment: I edited the answer - there was a small error. The above example is working as intended. Please note that all 3 columns are assumed to be strings.

Comment: Yes it not listing any row ... Only displaying column Name

Comment: The datatype resulting from the "input" function is string - so the variables ending on _in are string values. To compare them with the values in df1 (data not visible in your answer) the column types has to be all string for the 3 columns to work. you can check the data types by running: "df1.dtypes" (they should say "object" to be correct). I tested this on dummy data successfully.

Comment: Yes , You are correct my df1['batteryserialnumber'] is already in String(not str) dtype ...and  other column are datetime64[ns] dtype ..how to convert that...show me the sample code. if it ok with.

Comment: import pandas as pd 
ts = pd.to_datetime(str(df1['Date'])) 
df1['Date'] = ts.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')